# Update cart button removing item from cart

Tags: commerce

I am working on an issue presented to me on a Drupal Commerce site. For some reason, when you click on the update cart button on the cart page, without actually making any changes, the top item in the cart is removed.

Any ideas?

Comment: That doesn't really help. Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: That's the problem, not getting any errors.

Comment: I'd post this issue on drupal.org

Comment: How do I know if ajax is enabled on the cart? And why would that effect things here?

Comment: Sorry that's probably unrelated. Have you done any custom programming or anything?

Comment: Not that I know of. I took over this site and it seems to be a basic Drupal Commerce installation. I'm going to to try debugging a bit and see what I find.

Comment: I just noticed this on one of my installs just now. @user1015214 did you ever find the source of your issue?

Comment: @NigelWaters - no, I did not.